Taking Values from tkinter input boxes to be used as input variables in another function
I am currently working on building a data analysis program for my research, and just trying to make it more user-friendly for the undergrads in my lab.
I am trying to take the user input of several textboxes to be used as variables for reading a csv file and pulling data from it. Essentially I am asking the user "which columns in the csv do you want to pull" and taking that input to pull data from said column.
It currently works if I manually input which headers I need:
def plot_eye_data(eye_data, fig):
    fig.clear()  # Clear previous plots

    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(311)

    # Plot Left Eye
    ax1.plot(eye_data['Timestamp'], eye_data['LeftGazeX'], label='LGaze X')
    ax1.plot(eye_data['Timestamp'], eye_data['LeftGazeY'], label='LGaze Y')
    ax1.set_xlabel('Timestamp')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Gaze Position')
    ax1.set_title('Left Eye Gaze Position')
    ax1.legend()
    ax1.grid(True)

But I am not sure where I am going wrong when using Tkinter to get inputs.

# graph fxn
def plot_eye_data(eye_data, fig, time, leftx, lefty):
    fig.clear()  # Clear previous plots
    
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(311)

    # Plot Left Eye
    ax1.plot(eye_data[time], eye_data[leftx], label='LGaze X')
    ax1.plot(eye_data[time], eye_data[lefty], label='LGaze Y')
    ax1.set_xlabel('Timestamp')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Gaze Position')
    ax1.set_title('Left Eye Gaze Position')
    ax1.legend()
    ax1.grid(True)
# button fxns
def leftx_name():
    global leftx
    leftx = LeftX_Head_entry.get()
    return leftx
def lefty_name():
    global lefty
    lefty = LeftY_Head_entry.get()
    return lefty
def time_name():
    global time
    time = Time_Head_Entry.get()
    return time
# Initialize the main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Eye Data Classification")
# Left side - Controls, File Input Selection, and Text

# data selection window
data_select = tk.Toplevel(root)
data_select.transient(root)
data_select.maxsize(500, 500)

input_folder_label = tk.Label(data_select, text="Input Folder:")
input_folder_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")
input_folder_entry = tk.Entry(data_select, width=20)
input_folder_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan= 1, padx=5, pady=5)
tk.Button(data_select, text="Browse", command=browse_input_folder).grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
LeftX_Head_input = tk.Label(data_select, text="LeftX Header")
LeftX_Head_input.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")
LeftX_Head_entry = tk.Entry(data_select, width=20)
LeftX_Head_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan= 2, padx=5, pady=5)

LeftY_Head_input = tk.Label(data_select, text="LeftY Header")
LeftY_Head_input.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")
LeftY_Head_entry = tk.Entry(data_select, width=20)
LeftY_Head_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan= 2, padx=5, pady=5)

Time_Head_input = tk.Label(data_select, text="Time Header")
Time_Head_input.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")
Time_Head_Entry = tk.Entry(data_select, width=20)
Time_Head_Entry.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan= 2, padx=5, pady=5)
tk.Button(data_select, width = 5, text="Pull Data", command=lambda: [handle_pull_data(), rightx_name(), righty_name(),lefty_name(),leftx_name(),time_name()]).grid(row=6, column=1, pady=5, sticky="ew")

There is other inputs (hence the tkinter window will look yucky)
I was expecting it to be able to grab the contents of said textbox, then use that value in pulling the data from the csvs and graphing it, but it just tells me the variables in the plot_eye_data are undefined. When telling it to print the contents of a textbox it can:
print(leftx)

But won't use that variable in the graph. However hard-coding that variable:
leftx = LeftEyeX

Correctly grabs the column.
Update:
Here is the function for calling the plots.
def handle_pull_data():
    global current_file_path, eye_data, input_files
    if input_files:
        file = input_files.pop(0)
        current_file_path = os.path.join(input_folder_entry.get(), file)
        eye_data = read_eye_data(current_file_path)
        update_plots()
    else:
        current_file_path = ""  # No more files to process
        update_folder_counters()
def update_plots():
    if current_file_path:
        plot_eye_data(eye_data, fig, leftx, lefty, rightx, righty)
        plot_canvas.draw()

The other tk window displays the graph, then based on user input moves the current data file to a folder, then displays the next csv file's data as a graph.

first create normal function instead of using list to execute many functions in command= because it unreadable, and it doesn't allow to use print() to see what is executed and what you have in variables.

It is better to provide a [mre] as currently there is no code on how you call plot_eye_data().

the simplest: use leftx = LeftX_Head_entry.get() and other functions directly in plot_eye_data and assign plot_eye_data to command=. OR create one function which gets all values and it execute plot_eye_data with these values - and assign this function to command=

now I see your problem - you run handle_pull_data() before rightx_name() and othe functions - but you should run handle_pull_data() as last function. See my answer - I first get LeftX_Head_entry.get(),etc, and later I run plot_eye_data()

see my new answer.

Now I see your function.
You run handle_pull_data() as first - before rightx_name(), righty_name(),lefty_name(),leftx_name(),time_name()
so handle_pull_data() runs update_plots() which runs plot_eye_data() before you run rightx_name(), righty_name(),lefty_name(),leftx_name(),time_name()
and this is problem.
First you have to get values from widgets and later run handle_pull_data() which runs plot_eye_data() (which needs these values from widgets).

def get_data_and_show_plot():
    # first get data
    global leftx
    global lefty
    global time

    leftx = LeftX_Head_entry.get()
    lefty = LeftY_Head_entry.get()
    time = Time_Head_Entry.get()

    # later run function which will run `plot_eye_data(leftx, lefty, time)
    handle_pull_data()

# --- main ---

tk.Button(data_select, text="Pull Data", command=get_data_and_show_plot, ...)


OR you should get data directly when you need it
def update_plots():
    if current_file_path:
        leftx = LeftX_Head_entry.get()
        lefty = LeftY_Head_entry.get()
        time = Time_Head_Entry.get()
        #rightx = ...
        #righty = ...

        plot_eye_data(eye_data, fig, leftx, lefty, rightx, righty)
        plot_canvas.draw()

And this doesn't need global variable

def handle_pull_data():     global current_file_path, eye_data, input_files     if input_files:         file = input_files.pop(0)         current_file_path = os.path.join(input_folder_entry.get(), file)         eye_data = read_eye_data(current_file_path)         update_plots()     else:         current_file_path = ""  # No more files to process         update_folder_counters() def update_plots():     if current_file_path:         plot_eye_data(eye_data, fig, leftx, lefty, rightx, righty)         plot_canvas.draw()

@stanley1O1 you should put it in question - it will be more readable and more people may see it - so more people may help you. And show where it is in code which you already have in question - is it before button or after button or execute by button.

Sorry was struggling there. What do you mean by before button or after button? The data plotting aspect? If so it's after this input.

Trying the second option you provided gives me a key error:
KeyError: <tkinter.Entry object .!toplevel.!entry6>
Whereas your first suggestion only I think would show for a single graph, whereas I need it to redraw the graph for each data file (using the same header selection for each one).

if you have key error then you probably deleted widget. It seems you have more complex code - so problem can be more complex. You may have to reorganize your code - but still you have to first get values from widgets and later run handle_pull_data or any function which has to run plot_eye_data or has to redraw any plot.
